# How do I install Ubuntu 11.10 on an Acer travelmate 240

Tags: 11.10, boot, wubi, windows-xp

So far I have downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 and created both a stick and a dvd, but I cant get the system (acer travelmate 240) to boot from either.

Of course I have changed the system bootmenu to do so. Also I cant install from wubi. It simply stops with a backend error. Any ideas...

Comment: What do you mean by 'can not boot', why not? Have you changed the boot order in the BIOS? Can you also post the computer specs like RAM, CPU, graphics.

Comment: please Bjarne, provide some more information, what kind of backend error? More details will help with your problem =)

Comment: The 'backend' error is a wubi bug, but it only occurs after the ISO is rejected. So there is likely a problem with the DVD (which explains why you can't boot from it) and perhaps the ISO (which might explain why the USB stick fails as well)

Answer (score 2):

bcbc appears to have essentially answered the question in a comment:

> The 'backend' error is a wubi bug, but it only occurs after the ISO is
>   rejected. So there is likely a problem with the DVD (which explains
>   why you can't boot from it) and perhaps the ISO (which might explain
>   why the USB stick fails as well)

– [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) [Feb 28 '12 at 17:42](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108505/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-11-10-on-an-acer-travelmate-240#comment127395_108505)

So the error only happens after Wubi looked at the files on the CD and found it not to be the right file. This is usually due a corrupted or damaged ISO or CD/DVD/USB, so:

1. [MD5 test the ISO image.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) If it's bad, download the ISO again (and MD5 test that one too).
2. If your DVD and USB flash drive were created from an ISO image with a valid MD5SUM:

   - Make sure you are [writing the USB flash drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [burning the DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) correctly. Try making them again. (You'll need a new DVD but you can use the same flash drive.)
   - [Try burning the DVD at the slowest possible speed.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) This can sometimes reduce the risk of errors, or of physical damage to the DVD's surface if your DVD media are not entirely compatible with your DVD writer. (This applies to CD's too, to a degree.)
   - That should let you install a normal Ubuntu system, alongside (or in place of) your Windows system. I recommend that, as it performs a bit better and is considerably easier to fix if something goes wrong. However, if you prefer to use Wubi, you can install without having to prepare a CD/DVD or USB drive at all. Just make an empty folder, and put the ISO image and `wubi.exe` in the folder. (You can [get `wubi.exe` here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer).) Then run `wubi.exe`.

Also please note that if you're able to boot an Ubuntu CD/DVD or USB flash drive, you can test the burn/write itself [using this method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) (also [explained here](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html)). This is highly advisable, especially if you've already experienced problems like you have.